# Replace macro with function

Tags: c++, c++98

I have a piece of macro which I used to check for opengl related error

```
#if (GL_ERROR_CHECK == On)
#define GL_CHECK(x)                                                                                                    \
    x;                                                                                                                 \
    {                                                                                                                  \
        GLenum glError = glGetError();                                                                                 \
        if(glError != GL_NO_ERROR)                                                                                     \
        {                                                                                                              \
            std::cout << "GL Error: " << glError << " at " << __FILE__ << ", " << __LINE__ << std::endl;               \
        }                                                                                                              \
    }
#else
#define GL_CHECK(x)  x;
#endif
```

and using it as such

```
GL_CHECK(glGenFramebuffers(1, (GLuint*)&m_u32FboID));
GL_CHECK(glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, m_u32FboID));
```

I am wondering if there is any way to replace this macro with a proper c++ function?

Comment: FYI: your error handling code is wrong. Even a single OpenGL function is capable of delivering *multiple* OpenGL errors. So [you have to loop until you get `GL_NO_ERROR`](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Error#Catching_errors_.28the_hard_way.29).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using OpenGL 4.3 and above you can use the Debug Callback instead so you don't have to wrap every GL function in a Macro: [Check it out here](http://docs.gl/gl4/glDebugMessageCallback)

To enable everything:

```
glDebugMessageCallback(some_callback_function, nullptr);
glDebugMessageControl(GL_DONT_CARE, GL_DONT_CARE, GL_DONT_CARE, 0, nullptr, true);
```

With for example, this function:

```
void gl_debug_callback(GLenum source, GLenum type, GLuint id, GLenum severity,
                       GLsizei length, const GLchar* message, const void* userParam)
{
    std::cerr << "GL Debug Message: " << message << '\n';
}
```

Beware that this will sometimes output messages that are not errors, so you could consider switching on the severity for example, or be more restrictive about what you enable with the `...MessageControl` function.

Comment: But source location (`__FILE__`, `__LINE__`) is lost.

Comment: @Jarod42 You can, for example, add a breakpoint in the debug callback if the severity is high enough, and if you step out of the function or look at the call stack you can see where it happened.

Comment: It supposes that it is done on "local" machine. we cannot get those information from users' log for example.

Answer (score 2):

> I am wondering if there is any way to replace this macro with a proper c++ function?

I think the macro is a sound option in this case. One of the main benefits of using the macro is that you are able to use `__FILE__` and `__LINE__`  as part of the message.

You could move some of the code to a function but the macro still serves a purpose.

```
void checkForError(char const* file, int line)
{
   GLenum glError = glGetError();
   if(glError != GL_NO_ERROR)
   {
      std::cout << "GL Error: " << glError << " at " << file << ", " << line << std::endl;
   }
}

#if (GL_ERROR_CHECK == On)
#define GL_CHECK(x) x; checkForError(__FILE__, __LINE__);
#else
#define GL_CHECK(x) x;
#endif
```

Comment: MACRO can be entirely removed with [std::experimental::source_location](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/source_location) (but still experimental :-/ )...

Comment: @Jarod42 GCC has `__builtin_LINE()` and `__builtin_FILE()`, which do a similar thing.